# Failover between Primary and Secondary Web Server ASP.Net Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, dns, failover

I have a asp.net web application which is hosted on two different servers one being primary other being secondary.

Using DNSMadeEasy I have setup a dns failover when primary server goes down secondary server takes up.

This setup is working fine according to the requirements however there is one last catch.

My application uses a windows service for the purpose of billing.

The billing service is always running on primary server and always stopped at secondary server.

I want that when dns failover occurs it should automatically start the billing service on secondary server and when dns switches back to primary the billing service should be stopped on secondary server.

What do I need to do to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Changing your architecture a bit would help (as long as you can make these changes):

1. Put a load balancer (HAProxy, NGINX, etc) in front of both web servers.
2. Run the ASP.NET app and billing service on *both* web servers.
3. Re-architect your billing service so that it can run from both services *at the same time* without interference.

You're already running the standby, so you'll get lots of benefits to this:

- better scalability: load is shared between web servers/billing services
- zero-downtime updates: remove each web server one at a time from the load balancer, do your update and then add back into rotation.
- robustness: if one web server fails, you automatically have an architecture that doesn't have to worry about DNS TTL problems and will failover automatically.

If you can't really change much of your architecture, here's an idea:

Listen for the first web request to the Secondary web server and then start the service when it occurs. Depending on how it's designed, you may need to stop the billing service on the Primary.